# MVC 3 WebGrid Trying to Control Every Row's Permission

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

Why is this column not showing the links when I can see that the dictionary contains the keys and values. It looks like the index "item.Name" is not resolving. It was working fine before when I didn't have the permission if blocks. The plain format: `@<text>@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new {id = item.Id})</text>` works.

```
grid.Column(header: "Actions", format: @<text>
                 @if(Model.Permissions.ContainsKey(item.Name))
                 {
                   var permissions = Model.Permissions[item.Name];
                   if (permissions.Contains("Read"))
                   {
                      @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new {id = item.Id})
                   }
                   if (permissions.Contains("Update"))
                   {
                       @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {id = item.Id})
                   }
                 }</text>)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually works as intended. I had a typo in the string being searched in the list here `permissions.Contains("Update")` and `permissions.Contains("Read")`. "Update" and "Read" are something in the form "Read_x" and "Update_x". I should know not to use string literals even if I planned to refactor them later.